# Creating an Ad on TikTok sandbox account is requesting "identity_id" v.1.3. Where can i find it

Tags: tiktok, tiktok-api

I'm using v1.3 and i want to create and add, however it is requesting the identity_id which i do not know where to find it.

"identity_id": "xxxxxxxxx",

This is my end point https://sandbox-ads.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.3/ad/create/

I tried commenting it out but it seems mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this today and found this tidbit in the TikTok documentation (https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1767309272869890&rid=68wfzvwt9ov):

```
I could not call the /v1.3/ad/create/ endpoint in the sandbox environment and the response said an identity_id and identity_type is required.

identity_id and identity_type are required in /v1.3/ad/create/, but currently, the sandbox doesn't support the identity related endpoints. As a workaround, you can use the /v1.2/ad/create/ endpoint instead, which only requires the identity_id and identity_type parameters when creating Spark Ads.
```